# Dynamic key within @Messages

Tags: angularjs, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.3

Is there anyway to use an dynamic key inside @Messages i18n on Play framework? Something like that

```
@Messages("views.status.{{schedule.status | lowercase}}")
```

It's evaluating the key correct but does not get the value on my messages file. The code above evaluates in views.status.pendent instead of Pendent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation of expression `{{schedule.status | lowercase}}` happens on client side, whereas resolving `@Message()` argument happens on server side, thus it is impossible to resolve it. Instead, define your message key as follows:

`view.status.PENDANT=Pendet`

and call it:

`@Messages("view.status." + schedule.status)`